# Drawing from one panel class to another panel class.

Tags: java, graphics, jpanel, draw, paintcomponent

I have two classes. The first class is called Fishy1, and the second class is called Fishy2. This is the code for my first class:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Fishy1 extends JPanel {

Fishy1 fishy1 = new Fishy1();

/* Graphics goes here */
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawOval(50, 50, 50, 50);

}

}
```

As you can see, the code basically draws an oval in fishy1. And here is the code for my second class:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Fishy2 extends JPanel {

Fishy2 fishy2 = new Fishy2();

}
```

As you can see, in the second class, there is no paintComponet method to draw to fishy2. So, my question is, is there a way to draw to the second class using the paintComponent method in the first class? If there's no way to do it, please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: Not sure I understand you, but what about deriving `Fishy2` from `Fishy1`? This way, it inherits its `paintComponent` method.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve graphics replication between 2 swing classes at same time

```
public class Fishs extends JPanel {

    //Static list, all fishes panel will display the same objects at same positions
    private static List<OvalObj> lstOvalObjects;

    public Fishs() {
        //if the list is null just initialize it.
       lstOvalObjects = lstOvalObjects == null? new ArrayList():lstOvalObjects;
    }

    /* Graphics goes here */
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        lstOvalObjects.forEach(ovalObject ->  g.drawOval(ovalObject.getX(), ovalObject.getY(), ovalObject.getWidth(), ovalObject.getHeight()));
    }

    public static List<OvalObj> getLstOvalObjects() {
        return lstOvalObjects;
    }

    public static void setLstOvalObjects(List<OvalObj> lstOvalObjects) {
        Fishs.lstOvalObjects = lstOvalObjects;
    }

}
```

The oval object:

```
public class OvalObj{
        private int x,y,width,height;
        public OvalObj(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.width = width;
            this.height = height;
        }

        public int getX() {
            return x;
        }

        public void setX(int x) {
            this.x = x;
        }

        public int getY() {
            return y;
        }

        public void setY(int y) {
            this.y = y;
        }

        public int getWidth() {
            return width;
        }

        public void setWidth(int width) {
            this.width = width;
        }

        public int getHeight() {
            return height;
        }

        public void setHeight(int height) {
            this.height = height;
        }

    }
```

Implementation:

```
        //First Frame
        JFrame frame1 = new JFrame();
        frame1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        //First Fish Panel that will go to frame1
        Fishs fish1 = new Fishs();
        fish1.setVisible(true);

        frame1.add(fish1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame1.pack();
        frame1.setVisible(true);


        //Second Frame
        JFrame frame2 = new JFrame();
        //Second Fish Panel that will go to frame2
        Fishs fish2 = new Fishs();
        fish2.setVisible(true);
        frame2.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame2.add(fish2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame2.pack();
        frame2.setVisible(true);

        /// you can add many objects to draw as you like in a static way anywhere in your code, they will render in every fish panel at same time
        Fishs.getLstOvalObjects().add(new OvalObj(0, 0, 50, 50));
        Fishs.getLstOvalObjects().add(new OvalObj(20, 20, 50, 50));
```